# Defining a function that counts relative frequency of Amino Acids

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I'm trying to calculate codon frequency within a given sequence of DNA.

For example:

```
sequence = 'ATGAAGAAA'
codons = ['ATG', 'AAG', 'AAA']
```

for XX in codons:

```
frequency  = codons.count(XX)/(codons.count(XX)+codons.count(XX2)+codons.count(XX3))
```

Note that XX2 and XX3 will not always be in the sequence. Some codons may or may not have multiple codons.

Example: Lysine has 2 codons, AAA and AAG

so the frequency of

```
AAA = codons.count('AAA')/(codons.count('AAA') + codons.count('AAG'))
```

How can I do this for EVERY codon in the list? How do I account for multiple codons?

Comment: as of now, I'm doing this the long way and calcuating the frequence for EACH amino acid and their degenerate codons and if the sequence doesn't contain that amino acid I end up getting an error message.

Comment: A bit of psuedo code for non bio informatics people would be helpful :)

Comment: Not sure if it is helpful, but you can look at regular expressions. They are especially helpful for string manipulation. You may be interested in re.findall

Comment: I recon this could be done very nicely in Mathematica. Perhaps you would consider adding this tag?. If you prefer not to, I won't post, of course. +1 An interesting question. How long is your DNA  sequence?

Comment: I was writing an answer to another question of you that asked how to define a function to record results in a file, when this question disappeared , and I can't find it again. So I added the function in my following answer, using the result that my solution was already giving.

Answer (score 6):

use defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(int)

for aa in mysecuence:
    mydict[aa] +=1
```

This works for aminoacids (proteins).
For codons, you should iterate on the sequence in 3 positions steps to get the keys of the defaultdict. For example:

```
>>> mysec = "GAUCACTUGCCA"
>>> a = [mysec[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(mysec), 3)]
>>> print a


['GAU', 'CAC', 'TUG', 'CCA']
```

**EDIT:** If you want to calculate degeneration, you should prepare a dictionary relating each codon (key) with its degenerated codons (value, list of codons). To calculate the frecuency,
from the defaultdict you can get the counts for each codon, then for each codon you calculate the sum of the counts of the degenerated codons read from the dictionary of codons indicated above. Then you can calculate the frecuency.

**EDIT 2: Here you have a real example:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

#the first 600 nucleotides from GenBank: AAHX01097212.1
rna = ("tcccccgcagcttcgggaacgtgcgggctcgggagggaggggcctggcgccgggcgcgcg"
       "cctgcgccccaccccgccccaccctggcgggtctcgcgcgcccggcccgcctcctgtcaa"
       "ccccagcgcggcggtcaggtggtccccagcccttggccccagcctccagcttcctggtcc"
       "ctcgggctctgagtcctgtctccggcagatcgcctttctgattgttctcctgcgcagctg"
       "gaggtgtatagcccctagccgagctatggtgcctcagcagatgtgaggaggtagtgggtc"
       "aggataaacccgcgcactccataataacgtgccagggctcagtgacttgggtctgcatta")

seq = rna.upper().replace('T', 'U')

#RNA codon table from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_code
degenerated = (('GCU', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG'),
               ('UUA', 'UUG', 'CUU', 'CUC', 'CUA', 'CUG'),
               ('CGU', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGG', 'AGA', 'AGG'),
               ('AAA', 'AAG'), ('AAU', 'AAC'), ('GAU', 'GAC'),
               ('UUU', 'UUC'), ('UGU', 'UGC'), ('CCU', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG'),
               ('CAA', 'CAG'), ('UCU', 'UCC', 'UCA', 'UCG', 'AGU', 'AGC'),
               ('GAA', 'GAG'), ('ACU', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG'),
               ('GGU', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG'), ('CAU', 'CAC'), ('UAU', 'UAC'),
               ('AUU', 'AUC', 'AUA'), ('GUU', 'GUC', 'GUA', 'GUG'),
               ('UAA', 'UGA', 'UAG'))

#prepare the dictio of degenerated codons
degen_dict = {}
for codons in degenerated:
    for codon in codons:
        degen_dict[codon] = codons

#query_codons
max_seq = len(seq)
query_codons = [seq[i:i+3] for i in range(0, max_seq, 3)]

#prepare dictio of counts:
counts = defaultdict(int)
for codon in query_codons:
    counts[codon] +=1

#actual calculation of frecuencies
data = {}
for codon in query_codons:
    if codon in  degen_dict:
        totals = sum(counts[deg] for deg in degen_dict[codon])
        frecuency = float(counts[codon]) / totals
    else:
        frecuency = 1.00

    data[codon] = frecuency

#print results
for codon, frecuency in data.iteritems():
    print "%s  -> %.2f" %(codon, frecuency)


#produces:
GUC  -> 0.57
AUA  -> 1.00
ACG  -> 0.50
AAC  -> 1.00
CCU  -> 0.25
UAU  -> 1.00
..........
GCU  -> 0.19
GAU  -> 1.00
UAG  -> 0.33
CUC  -> 0.38
UUA  -> 0.13
UGA  -> 0.33
```

Comment: Yes, ive done that already. The issue I'm having is that Amino acids can have up to 6 other codons. I need to calculate the frequency of those codons based on whether or not the other codons are available in the sequence. if they aren't I keep getting an error message saying that I'm dividing by zero

Comment: That's actually in the direction I'm heading. How do I get the counts of the degenerated codons? What if those degenerate codons ARENT in my list of codons?

Comment: @Francis the code in my new edit takes care of everything. if the codon isnt in the degenerated codon list its frecuency is 1.

Answer (score 2):

If your sequence is in the correct reading frame:

```
>>> import collections
>>> 
>>> code = {     'ttt': 'F', 'tct': 'S', 'tat': 'Y', 'tgt': 'C',
...              'ttc': 'F', 'tcc': 'S', 'tac': 'Y', 'tgc': 'C',
...              'tta': 'L', 'tca': 'S', 'taa': '*', 'tga': '*',
...              'ttg': 'L', 'tcg': 'S', 'tag': '*', 'tgg': 'W',
...              'ctt': 'L', 'cct': 'P', 'cat': 'H', 'cgt': 'R',
...              'ctc': 'L', 'ccc': 'P', 'cac': 'H', 'cgc': 'R',
...              'cta': 'L', 'cca': 'P', 'caa': 'Q', 'cga': 'R',
...              'ctg': 'L', 'ccg': 'P', 'cag': 'Q', 'cgg': 'R',
...              'att': 'I', 'act': 'T', 'aat': 'N', 'agt': 'S',
...              'atc': 'I', 'acc': 'T', 'aac': 'N', 'agc': 'S',
...              'ata': 'I', 'aca': 'T', 'aaa': 'K', 'aga': 'R',
...              'atg': 'M', 'acg': 'T', 'aag': 'K', 'agg': 'R',
...              'gtt': 'V', 'gct': 'A', 'gat': 'D', 'ggt': 'G',
...              'gtc': 'V', 'gcc': 'A', 'gac': 'D', 'ggc': 'G',
...              'gta': 'V', 'gca': 'A', 'gaa': 'E', 'gga': 'G',
...              'gtg': 'V', 'gcg': 'A', 'gag': 'E', 'ggg': 'G'
...         }
>>> def count_codons(cds):
...     counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
...     for i in range(0,len(cds),3):
...        codon = cds[i:i+3]
...        counts[codon] += 1
...     return counts
... 
>>> def translate(cds, code):
...     return "".join((code[cds[i:i+3]] for i in range(0, len(cds), 3)))
... 
>>> seq = 'ATGAAGAAA'
>>> 
>>> codon_counts = count_codons(seq.lower())
>>> trans_seq = translate(seq.lower(), code)
>>> 
>>> [(codon, code[codon], float(codon_counts[codon])/trans_seq.count(code[codon])) for codon in codon_counts.keys()]
[('atg', 'M', 1.0), ('aag', 'K', 0.5), ('aaa', 'K', 0.5)]
>>>
```

**other info:**

I think you are asking to find something called codon usage.

There are tools online which allow you to find codon usage. This one also allows for offline use.

http://www.bioinformatics.org/sms2/codon_usage.html

and results (in this 'Fraction' is what you are asking for):

```
Results for 9 residue sequence "sample sequence one" starting "ATGAAGAAA"
AmAcid   Codon     Number        /1000     Fraction   .. 

Ala      GCG         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Ala      GCA         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Ala      GCT         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Ala      GCC         0.00         0.00         0.00 

Cys      TGT         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Cys      TGC         0.00         0.00         0.00 

Asp      GAT         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Asp      GAC         0.00         0.00         0.00 

Glu      GAG         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Glu      GAA         0.00         0.00         0.00 

Phe      TTT         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Phe      TTC         0.00         0.00         0.00 

Gly      GGG         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Gly      GGA         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Gly      GGT         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Gly      GGC         0.00         0.00         0.00 

His      CAT         0.00         0.00         0.00 
His      CAC         0.00         0.00         0.00 

Ile      ATA         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Ile      ATT         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Ile      ATC         0.00         0.00         0.00 

Lys      AAG         1.00       333.33         0.50 
Lys      AAA         1.00       333.33         0.50 

Leu      TTG         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Leu      TTA         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Leu      CTG         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Leu      CTA         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Leu      CTT         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Leu      CTC         0.00         0.00         0.00 

Met      ATG         1.00       333.33         1.00 

Asn      AAT         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Asn      AAC         0.00         0.00         0.00 

Pro      CCG         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Pro      CCA         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Pro      CCT         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Pro      CCC         0.00         0.00         0.00 

Gln      CAG         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Gln      CAA         0.00         0.00         0.00 

Arg      AGG         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Arg      AGA         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Arg      CGG         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Arg      CGA         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Arg      CGT         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Arg      CGC         0.00         0.00         0.00 

Ser      AGT         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Ser      AGC         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Ser      TCG         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Ser      TCA         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Ser      TCT         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Ser      TCC         0.00         0.00         0.00 

Thr      ACG         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Thr      ACA         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Thr      ACT         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Thr      ACC         0.00         0.00         0.00 

Val      GTG         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Val      GTA         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Val      GTT         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Val      GTC         0.00         0.00         0.00 

Trp      TGG         0.00         0.00         0.00 

Tyr      TAT         0.00         0.00         0.00 
Tyr      TAC         0.00         0.00         0.00 

End      TGA         0.00         0.00         0.00 
End      TAG         0.00         0.00         0.00 
End      TAA         0.00         0.00         0.00
```

cusp is the codon usage tool from EMBOSS which also may be worth taking a look at.

You may want to checkout BioPython for working with biological sequences. I believe they have a codon usage module.

Answer (score 1):

[PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) is a parser module that has some nice debugging features; it is very good at tasks like this...

```
from ply import lex

tokens = (
    'CODON',
)
t_CODON = (
    r"ATG|"
    r"AAG|"
    r"AAF|"
    r"AAC|"
    r"BOB|"
    r"FOO|"
    r"BAR|"
    r"AAA"
)
def t_error(t):
    raise TypeError("Unknown codon '%s'" % (t.value,))
lex.lex()
sequence = "AAABOBAACAAAFOOAACBARAAAAAA"
ccount = dict()
total = 0.0
lex.input(sequence)
for tok in iter(lex.token, None):
    if ccount.get(tok.value, False):
        ccount[tok.value] += 1
    else:
        ccount[tok.value] = 1
    total += 1.0

for codon,count in ccount.items():
    print "Frequency of %s is %f" % (codon, count/total)
```

Running that code produces...

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ python codon.py
Frequency of BAR is 0.111111
Frequency of BOB is 0.111111
Frequency of FOO is 0.111111
Frequency of AAA is 0.444444
Frequency of AAC is 0.222222
```

I'm a little lost when you start introducing the chemical terminology, but you can probably take over from here...

Answer (score 1):

- a codon table containing ALL the 64 codons, even the non-degenarated ones (they constitute one element groups)
- counting the occurences of each codon's group at the same time that occurences of codons are counted during the iteration
- codon table comprising the names of coded amino acids -> a good display

code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# the first 600 nucleotides from GenBank: AAHX01097212.1
adn = ("tcccccgcagcttcgggaacgtgcgggctcgggagggaggggcctggcgccgggcgcgcg"
       "cctgcgccccaccccgccccaccctggcgggtctcgcgcgcccggcccgcctcctgtcaa"
       "ccccagcgcggcggtcaggtggtccccagcccttggccccagcctccagcttcctggtcc"
       "ctcgggctctgagtcctgtctccggcagatcgcctttctgattgttctcctgcgcagctg"
       "gaggtgtatagcccctagccgagctatggtgcctcagcagatgtgaggaggtagtgggtc"
       "aggataaacccgcgcactccataataacgtgccagggctcagtgacttgggtctgcatta")

arn = adn.upper().replace('T','U')

#RNA codon table from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_code
codon_table = ((('GCU', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG'),  'Alanine'),
               (('UUA', 'UUG', 'CUU', 'CUC', 'CUA', 'CUG'),  'Leucine'),
               (('CGU', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGG', 'AGA', 'AGG'),  'Arginine'),
               (('AAA', 'AAG'),  'Lysine'),
               (('AAU', 'AAC'),  'Asparagine'),
               (('AUG',),  'Methionine'),
               (('GAU', 'GAC'),  'Aspartic acid' ),              
               (('UUU', 'UUC'),  'Phenylalanine'),
               (('UGU', 'UGC'),  'Cysteine'),
               (('CCU', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG'),  'Proline') ,
               (('CAA', 'CAG'),  'Glutamine'),
               (('UCU', 'UCC', 'UCA', 'UCG', 'AGU', 'AGC'),  'Serine'),
               (('GAA', 'GAG'),  'Glutamic acid'),
               (('ACU', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG'),  'Threonine'),
               (('GGU', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG'),  'Glycine'),
               (('UGG',),  'Tryptophane'),
               (('CAU', 'CAC'),  'Histidine'),
               (('UAU', 'UAC'),  'Tyrosine'),
               (('AUU', 'AUC', 'AUA'),  'Isoleucine'),
               (('GUU', 'GUC', 'GUA', 'GUG'),  'Valine'),
               (('UAA', 'UGA', 'UAG'),  'STOP')            )

siblings = dict( (cod, codgroup) for codgroup,aa in codon_table for cod in codgroup )

cod_count, grp_count, freq = defaultdict(int), defaultdict(int), {}

for cod in (arn[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0,len(arn),3)):
    cod_count[cod] += 1
    grp_count[siblings[cod]] += 1

for cod in siblings.iterkeys(): # the keys of siblings are the 64 codons
    if siblings[cod] in grp_count:
        freq[cod] = float(cod_count[cod])/grp_count[siblings[cod]]
    else:
        freq[cod] = '-* Missing *-'


display = '\n'.join(aa.rjust(13)+\
                '\n'.join('%s  %-16s' % (cod.rjust(18 if i else 5),freq[cod])
                          for i,cod in enumerate(codgrp))
                for codgrp,aa in codon_table)


# editing addition:

def outputResults(filename,arn,codon_table,displ):

    li = ['This file is named %s' % filename]

    li.append('The sequence of ARN:\n%s' %\
              '\n'.join(arn[i:i+42] for i in xrange(0,len(arn),42)))
    li.append('Size of the sequence : '+str(len(arn)))

    li.append('Codon_table:\n'+\
              '\n'.join('%s : %s' % (u,v) for u,v in codon_table))

    li.append('Frequency results :\n'+displ)

    with open(filename,'w') as f:
        f.writelines('\n\n'.join(li))


outputResults('ARN_mem.txt',arn,codon_table,display)
print display
```

.

### EDIT

I've added a function outputResults() to show the manner to record data and results in a file

The resulting file's content is:

```
This file is named ARN_mem.txt

The sequence of ARN:
UCCCCCGCAGCUUCGGGAACGUGCGGGCUCGGGAGGGAGGGG
CCUGGCGCCGGGCGCGCGCCUGCGCCCCACCCCGCCCCACCC
UGGCGGGUCUCGCGCGCCCGGCCCGCCUCCUGUCAACCCCAG
CGCGGCGGUCAGGUGGUCCCCAGCCCUUGGCCCCAGCCUCCA
GCUUCCUGGUCCCUCGGGCUCUGAGUCCUGUCUCCGGCAGAU
CGCCUUUCUGAUUGUUCUCCUGCGCAGCUGGAGGUGUAUAGC
CCCUAGCCGAGCUAUGGUGCCUCAGCAGAUGUGAGGAGGUAG
UGGGUCAGGAUAAACCCGCGCACUCCAUAAUAACGUGCCAGG
GCUCAGUGACUUGGGUCUGCAUUA

Size of the sequence : 360

Codon_table:
('GCU', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG') : Alanine
('UUA', 'UUG', 'CUU', 'CUC', 'CUA', 'CUG') : Leucine
('CGU', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGG', 'AGA', 'AGG') : Arginine
('AAA', 'AAG') : Lysine
('AAU', 'AAC') : Asparagine
('AUG',) : Methionine
('GAU', 'GAC') : Aspartic acid
('UUU', 'UUC') : Phenylalanine
('UGU', 'UGC') : Cysteine
('CCU', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG') : Proline
('CAA', 'CAG') : Glutamine
('UCU', 'UCC', 'UCA', 'UCG', 'AGU', 'AGC') : Serine
('GAA', 'GAG') : Glutamic acid
('ACU', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG') : Threonine
('GGU', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG') : Glycine
('UGG',) : Tryptophane
('CAU', 'CAC') : Histidine
('UAU', 'UAC') : Tyrosine
('AUU', 'AUC', 'AUA') : Isoleucine
('GUU', 'GUC', 'GUA', 'GUG') : Valine
('UAA', 'UGA', 'UAG') : STOP

Frequency results :
      Alanine  GCU  0.1875          
               GCC  0.375           
               GCA  0.25            
               GCG  0.1875          
      Leucine  UUA  0.125           
               UUG  0.0             
               CUU  0.25            
               CUC  0.375   
etc.............
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've fully understood the question, but I think you need to split the calculations into two stages: first count how many times each codon occurs, and then work out the frequencies. I've come up with the following code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Initial sequence.
sequence = "AAABOBAACAAAFOOAACBARAAAAAA"

# Which codons are grouped together.
groups = (
    ('AAA', 'AAC'),
    ('BOB',),
    ('FOO', 'BAR', 'BAA'),
)

# Separate into list of codons.
codonList = []
for codons in range(0, len(sequence), 3):
    codonList.append(sequence[codons:codons+3])

# Count how many times each codon is used.
counts = defaultdict(int)
for codon in codonList:
    counts[codon] += 1

# Go through and calculate frequencies of each codon.
freqs = {}
for group in groups:
    total = float(sum(counts[codon] for codon in group))
    for codon in group:
        freqs[codon] = counts[codon] / total

# Done.
print freqs
```

Note the explicit conversion of `total` to a floating-point number in the last loop. If it is left as an integer, the subsequent division will be either 0 or 1 on Python 2.x, so we need to convert it to get a floating-point output. The output I get is:

```
blair@blair-eeepc:~$ python codons.py 
{'BAR': 0.5, 'AAC': 0.33333333333333331, 'BAA': 0.0, 'AAA': 0.66666666666666663, 'BOB': 1.0, 'FOO': 0.5}
```

Is this the sort of output you were looking for?